# Style theme giving an error

Tags: android, xml

I have a style that is supposed to apply to all `CardViews` known as `CardStyle`. When I apply the style to one of the cardView's theme it gives an error:

```
Error:(84, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@styles/CardStyle').
```

I haven't had much experience with styles before so it may be a simple fix.

CardView in main.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:theme="@styles/CardStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

<!-- content -->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

costum style in styles.xml

```
<style name="CardStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
</style>
```

What am I doing wrong or is there a different better way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I changed the name to `@style/CardStyle`. Right when I think I solved it, I get slammed with another error.

```
Render problem: Couldn't resolve resource @style/CardStyle
```

I don't know why this is...

Comment: `"@styles/CardStyle"` - It's `@style`, not `@styles`. You've got an extra `s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may correct the typo error, replace `android:theme="@styles/CardStyle"` with  `android:theme="@style/CardStyle"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:theme="@style/CardStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```